# I am trying to solve the N queen problem using backtracking but on compilation its giving the runtime error (dynamic-stack-buffer-overflow)

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++14

I am trying to solve the "N Queen Problem" using backtracking but due to some error it is showing runtime error. 
On compilation it displays runtime error and gives the message `dynamic-stack-buffer-overflow on address ******`

Checked the code many times but was unable to find the source of the problem

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<string>> solveNQueens(int n) {
        vector<vector<string>> result;
        vector<string> temp;
        int arr[n]={0};
        arr[0]=99;
        vector<int> queen;
        calc(result,n,temp,arr,0,queen);
        return result;
    }

    void calc(
        vector<vector<string>>& result,
        int n, vector<string>& temp,
        int * arr,
        int count,
        vector<int>& queen
    ) {
        if(count==n)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<queen.size();k++)
            {
                string s="";
                for(int m=1;m<=n;m++)
                {
                    if(m==queen[k])
                        s=s+'Q';
                    else
                        s=s+'.';
                }
                temp.push_back(s);
            }
            result.push_back(temp);
        }
        else{
            for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
            {
                if(arr[i]==0)
                {
                    int temp1[n]={0};
                    temp1[0]=99;
                    for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
                    {
                        temp1[j]=arr[j]+temp1[j];
                        if(arr[j]!=0)
                            temp1[j+1]++;
                    }
                    queen.push_back(i);
                    temp1[i]++;
                    calc(result,n,temp,temp1,count+1,queen);
                    queen.pop_back();
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: "On compilation" and "runtime error" are contradictory. If the program won't compile, we'll need at least the full compiler error message to help, and a [mre] will make helping much easier. If the program compiles but something goes wrong when you execute it, it's time to debug. If you're new to debugging, there are some hints at https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Just from looking at this, it could be that the compiler doesn't like that you declare `int arr[n]`. Some compilers, and newer standards I believe, will support this, but it's much safer to dynamically allocate in such a case.

Comment: @anonmess VLAs are only in C99+, but were never accepted into C++.

Comment: "newer standards I believe, will support this" - the construct is not, and never will be, part of C++

Comment: @Deduplicator Ah ok I wasn't sure, I'm much more familiar with C than especially >C++11.

Comment: There is a topic here about why `VLAs` are not part of `c++`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard

Comment: @drescherjm very interesting reading, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
            {
                if(arr[i]==0)
```

Valid indexes into `arr` are 0 through `n-1`. On the last iteration of this loop, when `i == n`, `arr[i]` exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an index out of bounds.

Similarly with `temp1[j]` and, even more so, `temp1[j+1]` in the inner loop.